# Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Store's New Project "DirectX App" won't compile vanilla

Tags: c++, directx, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 for Windows (This is the version for Windows Store).

I then read the quite helpful [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn481529.aspx) over at MSDN on DirectX for Windows Store.

It gives instructions as follows: Click new project. Click DirectX App. It should Compile and run.

It doesn't. Instead, I'm getting the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Sequence, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  pch.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(1): error C2018: unknown character '0x8'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(1): error C2018: unknown character '0x15'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x1'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '‘×ÿ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x5'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'H‹'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '|'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C3872: '0x24': this character is not allowed in an identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x15'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'L‹L$'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'L‹D$HH‹T$P3Éÿ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier ''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ë'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x4'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'H‹H‰'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ØH‹'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x8'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '×HƒÀ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'H‰'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '’×H‹'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ë×H‰'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ÖH‹„$H‰'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x3'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C3872: '0x4': this character is not allowed in an identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x2'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x17'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x14'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x1f'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2): error C2001: newline in constant
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2018: unknown character '0x8'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2018: unknown character '0x3'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2018: unknown character '0xe'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'AÿÁHƒÀ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2065: 'E' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '$'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'WHƒì'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'H‹ÙH'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): warning C4129: '$' : unrecognized character escape sequence
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2001: newline in constant
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2065: 'àþÿH‹ÏèD…Àt' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(3): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'string'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(4): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(4): error C2018: unknown character '0x1'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x5'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x40'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x8'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x1'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0xf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ÈÈH…Ét'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2086: 'int H‹' : redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(2) : see declaration of 'H‹'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'è–ðÿÿHƒ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '%'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C3699: '%' : cannot use this indirection on type 'int'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2530: '¶Èƒ' : references must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2530: '·Èƒ' : references must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x15'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'qÈÿ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2530: '´ÈH' : references must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ãùƒ'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ÈH…Ét'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2530: 'ÈH‹' : references must be initialized
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'è'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2065: 'ðÿÿHƒ' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2059: syntax error : '{'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x2'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x10'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x3'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C3872: '0x24': this character is not allowed in an identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x16'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x17'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C3872: '0x4': this character is not allowed in an identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2015: too many characters in constant
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x18'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x1c'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x11'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x6'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x13'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x7f'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2018: unknown character '0x12'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(5): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Obviously my internet search turned up nothing. I'm sorry, but I've never used DirectX before, and I simply hoped to start doing stuff with the sample, so I don't have any background on how to debug these errors. They sound not even related to DirectX.

This may or may not be important. I have had a number of problems with DirectX (not for development) before. A number of games I own will not start, complaining about DirectX doing something wrong. Whenever I try to run a DirectX runtime standalone installer, I get the message, "This version of DirectX is not compatible with the version of windows currently installed." I don't know if this is related. (And it's a whole other thing I've spent tons of time trying to fix, finding no information on, but that's a whole different story.)

I run Windows 8.1 (It was originally Windows 8 and I updated normally.) DXDiag says I have DirectX 11.

This has been quite frustrating, as when code doesn't work, I expect it to be my fault. When my compiler is given good code and it doesn't work, I get frustrated. Thank you for helping.

EDIT: Thanks to @Drop, for pointing out the obviously corrupted nature of xmemory0 (in contrast with the plaintext in the others in that folder, this file looked like a nuclear meltdown). So if any of you could simply copy and paste in their xmemory0 to an answer, (to save me the trouble of reinstalling) I would be very glad. Thanks!

EDIT 2: OK, looks like indeed there are a number of corrupted files and re-installing VS for Desktop and for Windows Store did nothing to fix them. I tried copying files from VS 2012, but those too give errors, this time unrelated to a corrupted file. So what I am now asking for is please a zipped up include directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include). Thank you!

Comment: `pch.cpp`? How did that happen? It totally looks like you're trying to compile the **binary** output of a precompiled header file as if it were C++ code.

Comment: Yep. Messed up environment.

Comment: Looks like your Visual Studio installation got corrupted. In particular, STL headers. Open in any text editor (notepad or visual studio), file `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0`. It must be human-readable C++ header file in ANSI-Latin encoding. You can add first few lines of it, to your question post, so we can see if it's ok.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it appears to be very corrupted! I'm currently in a mess of other things like updating drivers and checking for viruses (my computer temporarily stopped working today) so I don't really want to reinstall. Do you think you could just copy and paste in specifically your xmemory0? (I checked the rest of the file, they all look perfect)